# What's the generic & efficient trimming algorithm for Qt & std::string?

Tags: c++, string, qt, c++14, removing-whitespace

To remove front & back whitespaces, Qt offers `QByteArray::trimmed()`. But it makes a copy of the underlying string unnecessarily everytime.

Is there any generic & efficient way (preferably using templates) to trim whitespaces for `QByteArray, QString, std:: string`?

Comment: You tagged your question with c++14, so I guess `std::string_view` (C++17) is out of the question?

Comment: @Botje, yes our main compatibility is witih C++14 and C++17 is yet to be supported. Can you put your perspective in answer with C++17, provided that it supports Qt's string types as well.

Comment: If you don’t mind keeping the untrimmed version as the underlying QString, QStringView::trimmed might be an option (for QString).

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, that's the theme of the question. As already mentioned, `trimmed()` is inefficient and it's stupidity on the Qt's part that it always creates a new string. They should have given a non-const method such as `trim()` which works on the existing string.

Comment: I was talking about QString*View*::trimmed, not QString::trimmed

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, will it not create a copy? Moreover it's not available for `QByteArray`, which I am using mostly at places. I have posted an answer with an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simplistic way:

```
template<typename T>
T& Trim (T& value)
{
  auto pos = value.size();
  while(pos != 0 and value[--pos] == ' ');
  if(++pos < value.size())
    value.erase(pos);

  if(value.size() > 0)
  {
    pos = -1;
    while(value[++pos] == ' ');
    if(pos > 0)
      value.erase(0, pos);
  }
  return value;
}
```

Above will support all the types which have following methods like `std::string`:

- `size()`
- `operator[] const`
- `erase(pos, n)`

---

Qt just lacks the `erase()` (name is `remove()`) unfortunately. To support the Qt types `QString` and `QByteArray`, we can have following wrapper:

```
template<class String>
struct QtWrap
{
  String& m_Value;

  auto size () const { return m_Value.size(); }
  auto erase (int pos) { return m_Value.truncate(pos); }
  auto erase (int pos, int length) { return m_Value.remove(pos, length); }
  auto& operator[] (const int pos) const { return m_Value.data()[pos]; }
};
```

Usage:

```
QByteArray s;
QtWrap<QByteArray> qs{s};
Trim(qs);  // Tested OK in QtCreator: Modifies the underlying `s`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do similar things for each of them, but they don't use the same interface.

```
void trim(std::string & str)
{
    auto first = std::find_if_not(str.begin(), str.end(), [](unsigned char c){ return std::isspace(c); });
    auto last = std::find_if_not(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), [](unsigned char c){ return std::isspace(c); }).base();

    if (first != str.begin())
    {
        std::move(first, last, str.begin());
    }

    str.erase(last, str.end());
}

void trim(QString & str)
{
    auto first = std::find_if_not(str.begin(), str.end(), [](unsigned char c){ return std::isspace(c); });
    str.remove(0, first - str.begin());

    auto last = std::find_if_not(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), [](unsigned char c){ return std::isspace(c); }).base();
    str.resize(last - str.begin());
}
```